# mediapipe android example apps are not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mediapipe

I'm trying to run mediapipe android example apps([Check Here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/android/solutions)) but not working in android stuio.

I have downloaded the code from github and imported in my android studio (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1). Initially the error was the file name should end with .xml. so how to run this in android device. any ideas??

Comment: Please update your question to include the specific app you are trying to run, and paste the log of the error into your question.

Which example are you trying to run? MediaPipe has added [new solutions](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions) with [new examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/mediapipe) that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to implement FaseMesh using media pipe in android studio. I am able to implement it for image input but not able to video and camera input.